# using iRate to rate apps.. what do I need to change in order for this to work on my app?

Tags: ios, irate

Pls see the code.. if I dont use  [iRate sharedInstance].appStoreID will that be ok? I will only use

```
+ (void)initialize
{
    //configure iRate
    [iRate sharedInstance].applicationBundleID = com.companyblah.appblah;
}
```

can it redirect to my app just by using this code when I upload this to appstore? you see my app isnt uploaded yet so it doesnt have an appStoreID for me to put in.

sorry for being a noob

Comment: You can see AppStore ID in iTunes Connect as soon as you configure your app there.

Comment: thanks for the info Filip.. on my itunes connect i have this : Name:U***** Prefix:4********  ID:com.s*****.u*******                what's the appStoreID there? is it the Prefix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see AppStore ID in [iTunes Connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/) as soon as you configure your app there.

Go to **Manage Your Apps**, select your app if you already created it or create it now and when done look for **Apple ID** under App Information.

However, it's usually not required for iRate to work unless you have apps on multiple platforms with same bundle ID. Side note: applicationBundleID also doesn't need to be set manually, iRate can read it from your Info.plist. It's only there for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

+(void)initialize
{

```
[iRate sharedInstance].previewMode = YES; // For testing. Make "NO" while submitting on app store

//configure iRate
[iRate sharedInstance].appStoreID = appStoreId; //You need app store ID here

[iRate sharedInstance].daysUntilPrompt = 2;// Days
```

}